# Vaadin - GWT dependency always needed?

Tags: gwt, vaadin

Is the GWT mandatory in a deployment with Vaadin framework.

I mean is the Vaadin framework builded over the GWT and then not using GWT is not possible.
I ask because some manager asked me but I was not able to answer if it can be used separately or not.

I know the GWT does not need Vaadin but what about the inverse?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Vaadin without GWT. Vaadin 7 and 8 client side code is precompiled with GWT. Thus you need GWT only for adding new widgets to Vaadin 7 or 8.

Comment: Ok thanks. Your answer clarify the architecture diagram on the Vaadin web site at http://vaadin.com/demo#programming-model where the Vaadin Widget layer is surrounded by the GWT.

Answer (score 6):

Vaadin 7 and 8 have full copy of GWT built-in. No separate GWT dependency is thus needed any more.

Furthermore Vaadin version 10 onwards do not use use GWT for widgets anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I would refer the [stackoverflow tag definition of vaadin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vaadin]) at a first touch. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin) tells the same: Vaadin is built on GWT - meaning it is on the top of GWT, GWT is not on the top of Vaadin. The top can be always removed but the underlying basis not.

Comment: Joonas had it right. I did not know that although Vaadin is made upon GWT, no separate GWT installations are needed.